# How can I complete this Fibonacci sequence evaluation in R?

Tags: r, math, fibonacci

Greetings good people of Stackland!

Recently I was given this task

- Generate the Fibonacci sequence in any language
- Evaluate whether each value is odd or even
- Sum the even numbers such that their total is not >500,000

I chose to do this R, as I am learning the language and thought it would be a good exercise in doing so.

I have managed to complete step 2 of the task but haven't been able to proceed any further. Please see code and comments below.

```
   len <- 50
    fibvals <- numeric(len)
    fibvals[1] <- 1
    fibvals[2] <- 1
    for(i in 3:len) { fibvals[i] <- fibvals[i-1]+fibvals[i-2]}
    fibvals
     [1]           1           1           2           3           5
     [6]           8          13          21          34          55
    [11]          89         144         233         377         610
    [16]         987        1597        2584        4181        6765
    [21]       10946       17711       28657       46368       75025
    [26]      121393      196418      317811      514229      832040
    [31]     1346269     2178309     3524578     5702887     9227465
    [36]    14930352    24157817    39088169    63245986   102334155
    [41]   165580141   267914296   433494437   701408733  1134903170
    [46]  1836311903  2971215073  4807526976  7778742049 12586269025

    # Creates a variable called len in which the value 50 is stored
    # Creates a var called fibvals, which is a numeric datatype, which should have len (50) vals
    # Sets the value of the first entry in fibvals to 1
    # Sets the value of the second entry in fibvals to 1
    # Loop - "for (i in 3:len)" dictates that the loop should be executed between step 3 and step 50 (denoted by "len")
    # Loop - Defines a loop step "i" as being the result of the (current i - the before it) + (current i - i two before it)
    # Loop - Example 5 = (5-3) + (5-2) OR 2 + 3 = 5 | Example 21 = (21-13) + (21-8) OR  8 + 13 = 21 

    is.even <- function(x){ x %% 2 == 0 }

    # Creates a UDF to check if values are odd or even by using modulo. 
    If the remainder is 0 when any value is divided by 2, it is an even number 

is.even(fibvals)

 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[11] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[21]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[31] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[41] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

# Evaluates all Fibonacci values on odd or even property
```

What I need is a bit of guidance as to where I should go from here.
Should I create a data.table and query that using the SQL package, or is there a much more elegant and less cumbersome way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In step 3, do you mean that you are going to find all the combinations of even `fibvals`as long as the sum of the combination is smaller than 500000?

Comment: @Psidom - Apologies if that was unclear. Aim here is to sum ONLY the even fibvals, with the sum not exceeding 500,000. Is that any clearer?

Comment: But there are still many possibilities, for example, `2, 4, 6, 8, 10` and the threshold is `10`, should I sum `2 + 4` or `2 + 6`? You can not include all `2,4,6` into your sequence since their sum is `12`.

Comment: Interesting and very valid interpretation, but in your example where the threshold is 10, and assuming the summing is sequential, you'd only be able to sum 2+4, surely? Adding the next number would exceed the limit, giving 12 as you point out.

Comment: If sequentially, the ambiguity will be gone and I think some of the answers below give the correct method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sorting out the even number from first 50 fibonacci numbers you can use this

```
even_numbers <- fibvals[fibvals%%2==0]
```

Then by computing cumulative sum of those even numbers and imposing the condition of the maximum value of the sum, you can select those even numbers by this

```
cumsum(even_numbers)<500000
```

Therefore your desired fibonacci numbers are

```
even_numbers[cumsum(even_numbers)<500000]
```

and their `sum` is

```
sum(even_numbers[cumsum(even_numbers)<500000])
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it

```
fsum <- 0
for (i in 1:len) { if (is.even(fibvals[i]) && (fsum + fibvals[i])<=500000) {fsum = fsum + fibvals[i]}}
```

The sum would then be stored in `fsum`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with a recursive function:

```
getEvenWithFibber <- function(y = c(1,1), 
                          s = 0,
                          threshold = 500000) {
 if(s + y[1] + y[2] < threshold) 
    getEvenWithFibber(y = c(y[1] + y[2],y), s =  s + ifelse(y[1]%%2==0,y[1],0)) 
 else list(sum = s, seq = y, iseven = y%%2 == 0)
}


getEvenWithFibber()
```